# Apppool recycle side effects

Tags: iis, web, hosting

when we  **recycle app pool , will it crashes my website**.

we have a basic public website. does  recyclying the apppool every week causes the site to crash or it just kills the session of the users

we have *system of out memory issue* at the moment , until the we are recycling the app pool

Answer (score 1):

If you keep your sessions [InProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.ASPX) (default) then yes, recycling the application will kick out any logged in user, they will lose their sessions.

Out of Memory could be caused by many things. See [How to Troubleshoot Out of Memory Issues (System.OutOfMemoryException) in ASP.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2020006)

Comment: hi thanks for the info. we are investigationg the cause for it, meanwhile we are doing manual app pool recycle every week, just had a scare that the app pool recycle wont crash the site???

Comment: You can schedule recycling based on many things see [Configuring Recycling Settings for an Application Pool (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753179(v=ws.10).aspx)